# PyQt How do I implement a delete button to delete selected cells of a table?

Tags: python, inheritance, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget

So i have my main code here

```
class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.table_luni_anul_1 = TableWidget(anul_1, "Luni")
        self.ani_tab = QTabWidget()
        self.anul_1_tab = TabWidget()
        self.anul_1_tab.insert_tabs([self.table_luni_anul_1])
        self.ani_tab.addTab(self.anul_1_tab, "Anul 1")
        self.delete=DeleteWidget()

type here
```

And the classes DeleteWidget and TableWidget
DeleteWidget.py

```
class DeleteWidget(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self,ani):
        QPushButton.__init__(self)

        self.ani=ani
        self.setFixedSize(30, 260)
        self.setStyleSheet('QPushButton {font-size: 20px;}')
        self.setText('D\nE\nL\nE\nT\nE\n')
        self.clicked.connect(self.delete_data) # dont know where to put function that calls when pushbutton is pressed
```

TableWidget.py

```
class TableWidget(QTableWidget):

    def __init__(self, data, name):
        QTableWidget.__init__(self, 12, len(data))
        self.name = name
        self.data = data
        self.setData()
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setDragEnabled(False)
        # self.setDragDropMode(QTableWidget.InternalMove)  # Objects can only be drag/dropped internally and are moved instead of copied
        # self.setDragDropOverwriteMode(False)
        for i in range(len(self.data)): self.setColumnWidth(i, 80)

    def setData(self):
        horizontal_headers = []
        vertical_headers = []

        for n in self.data:
            horizontal_headers.append(n)
        self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(horizontal_headers)

        for i in range(8, 20):
            vertical_headers.append(f"{i}")
        self.setVerticalHeaderLabels(vertical_headers)
```

I have tried everything but cant get my head to understand how this should work. I want to delete selected cells of the user from the table.Not eliminate rows ,just delete content that is written.

Comment: you would need to get the currently selected cells from the table widget and clear their contents.

Comment: I know but i dont know how to pass the arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could look something like this

```
class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.table_luni_anul_1 = TableWidget(anul_1, "Luni")
        self.ani_tab = QTabWidget()
        self.anul_1_tab = TabWidget()
        self.anul_1_tab.insert_tabs([self.table_luni_anul_1])
        self.ani_tab.addTab(self.anul_1_tab, "Anul 1")
        self.delete=DeleteWidget()
        self.delete.clicked.connect(self.delete_selection)


    def delete_selection(self):
        for item in self.table_luni_anul_1.selectedItems():
            # ... this is were you would clear the items value
            item.setText('')
```